# How do I read an s3 bucket from AWS SAM local

Tags: aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I have a lambda that I wish to test locally using AWS SAM local. The lambda needs to read from an s3 bucket on the cloud. How do I allow this to happen from the AWS SAM local environment?

thanks

Angus

Comment: I'm amazed no-one has answered this yet! I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution? - Every time I try to emulate something with AWS SAM local I find I have to jump through hoops to simulate what I'm doing fairly easily on the console - its a shame because being able to develop locally would have some much needed advantages!

Comment: Please add your code to the question. We have no idea if you are running python, ruby, node, or whatever.